# Is it possible to replace this nested loop in pandas with numpy vectorization to speed up code processing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Data:

```
orderid         shopid  userid      event_time            timestamp 
31077182438530  10151   154282716   2019-12-27 00:33:02   1577406782    
31078679118082  10151   154282716   2019-12-27 00:58:00   1577408280    
31079250834942  10151   154282716   2019-12-27 01:07:30   1577408850    
31086252001110  10151   12825914    2019-12-27 03:04:12   1577415852    
31087365203493  10151   102963110   2019-12-27 03:22:46   1577416966
```

Current code:

```
shopid = df.shopid.values
userid = df.userid.values
event_time = df.timestamp.values
flag = np.zeros(shopid.shape, dtype=int)

current_shop = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if shopid[i] != current_shop:
        current_shop = shopid[i]
        prev_time = event_time[i] - 3600
        users = {userid[i]: 1}
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if (current_shop == shopid[j]) and (event_time[j] - event_time[i] <= 3600):
            if userid[j] not in users:
                users[userid[j]] = 0
            users[userid[j]] += 1
        else:
            break
    while j - i / len(users) < 3 and event_time[j-1] - prev_time > 3600:
        j -= 1
        users[userid[j]] -= 1
        if users[userid[j]] == 0:
            users.pop(userid[j])
    if j - i / len(users) >= 3:
        flag[i:j] = 1
    prev_time = event_time[i]
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is for each shop, find which user made 3 or more orders within 1 hour of any interval. So above I'm looping through each shop (1st loop), then looping through each shop's orders (2nd loop) and check if the time is within 1 hour, then add the user to a dict with the count of orders. After that I doing a decremental loop (3rd loop) to count number of orders / unique users and if less than 3, i will pop the user out of the dict. At the end, check for opposite condition and if valid, i set the flag to 1. The flag is then used to identify the specific orderid, the respective shop and user id.

Expected output:

```
orderid         shopid  userid      event_time            timestamp     flag
31077182438530  10151   154282716   2019-12-27 00:33:02   1577406782    1
31078679118082  10151   154282716   2019-12-27 00:58:00   1577408280    1
31079250834942  10151   154282716   2019-12-27 01:07:30   1577408850    1
31086252001110  10151   12825914    2019-12-27 03:04:12   1577415852    0
31087365203493  10151   102963110   2019-12-27 03:22:46   1577416966    0
```

Comment: I don't know a full answer to solve the time range filter, but as you want to perform this filter per user per shop, you could replace the manual loops categorizing the shops and users with `df.groupby(['shopid','userid'])` and work from there.

Comment: That's what I did but can't really figure out how these conditions can be addressed in the group. e.g. counting the number of orders / unique users in the one hour time frame for each shop. Also there's 220K+ orders so performance is another qn

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
df['event_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_time'])
```

This should give you the count for each shop on an hourly frequency

```
df.groupby(['shopid','userid', pd.Grouper(key='event_time',freq='H')]).count()
```

`df['flag'] = df.groupby(['shopid','userid', pd.Grouper(key='event_time',freq='H')])['userid'].count().values`

Here is the output i got

```
shopid  userid  event_time  orderid timestamp
0   10151   12825914    2019-12-27 03:00:00 1   1
1   10151   12825914    2019-12-27 07:00:00 1   1
2   10151   102963110   2019-12-27 03:00:00 1   1
3   10151   102963110   2019-12-27 04:00:00 1   1
4   10151   154282716   2019-12-27 00:00:00 2   2
5   10151   154282716   2019-12-27 01:00:00 1   1
6   10151   154282716   2019-12-27 03:00:00 1   1
7   10151   154282716   2019-12-27 04:00:00 1   1
8   10151   154282716   2019-12-27 14:00:00 1   1
```